# Codenameone NFC TAG Writer Native Interface call Tag is null Error

Tags: java, android, codenameone, nfc

I wanted to write to an NFC tag using a call to the native interface
Here is my Native impl file for android
The entrypoint function is `bindNFCwriter()`.

```
public class NewInterfaceImpl {

public String message="";

 

  public String Target = "Text to Write";
  private NfcAdapter     NFC_Adapter;
  private PendingIntent  NFC_PendingIntent;
  
  private boolean        writeMode = false;


LifecycleListener listener = new LifecycleListener() {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
message = "onCreate Served";

}
    public void onPause() {
message = "onPause";
  NFC_Adapter.disableForegroundDispatch(AndroidNativeUtil.getActivity());
}
    public void onDestroy() {
message = "onDestroy";
}
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle b) { message = "onSaveInstanceState";   }
    public void onLowMemory() {message = "onLowMemory"; }

    public void onResume() 
{ 

  Activity myActivity = AndroidNativeUtil.getActivity(); 
try{
    Intent intent = myActivity.getIntent(); 

  if (writeMode)
    { 
if (intent.getAction() != null){ 
     if (intent.getAction().equals(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED))
      {
        Tag detectedTag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
if(detectedTag == null){ 
message = "Tag is null"; 
return;}
     
  if(writeTag(buildNdefMessage(), detectedTag)){
message = "Success!";}else{
message = "Error: "+errorMsg;} ;

   
      }
}
    }
}catch(Exception xxx){message = "Exception: "+xxx.getMessage(); }
 

    }
};


    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

   

    public void bindNFCwriter() {

AndroidNativeUtil.addLifecycleListener(listener);

        if(AndroidNativeUtil.checkForPermission(Manifest.permission.NFC, "...")) { 
 NFC_Adapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(AndroidNativeUtil.getActivity().getApplicationContext());
  

    if (NFC_Adapter == null)
    {
message =  "Adapter is Null";
    
      return;
    }

try{
final Intent intent = new Intent(AndroidNativeUtil.getActivity().getApplicationContext(),AndroidNativeUtil.getActivity().getClass());
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
intent.setAction ("android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED");

    NFC_PendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(AndroidNativeUtil.getActivity().getApplicationContext(), 0, intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
}catch(Exception xxc){message =  "Error: "+xxc.getMessage(); return;}

enableTagWriteMode();

        }else{ message =  "no permission";}
    }


    public void unbindNFCwriter() {
  
    }

    public boolean isSupported() {
        return true;
    }


private void enableTagWriteMode()
  {
    writeMode = true;
    NFC_Adapter.enableForegroundDispatch(AndroidNativeUtil.getActivity(), NFC_PendingIntent, null, null);

  
  }

private void disableTagWriteMode()
  {
    writeMode = false;
   NFC_Adapter.disableForegroundDispatch(AndroidNativeUtil.getActivity());

  }

boolean writeTag(NdefMessage message, Tag tag)
  {
    int size = message.toByteArray().length;

    try
    {
      Ndef ndef = Ndef.get(tag);
      if (ndef != null)
      {
        ndef.connect();

        if (!ndef.isWritable())
        {
  
errorMsg = "Cannot write to this tag. This tag is read-only.";
          return false;
        }

        if (ndef.getMaxSize() < size)
        {
       errorMsg = "Greater than MaxSize.";
          return false;
        }

        ndef.writeNdefMessage(message);
       
        return true;
      }

     
      return false;

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
errorMsg = "Cannot write to this tag due to an Exception: "+e.getMessage();
    
    }

    return false;
  }

String errorMsg="";
private NdefMessage buildNdefMessage()
  {
    String data = Target;

    String mimeType = "text/plain";

    byte[] mimeBytes = mimeType.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    byte[] dataBytes = data.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    byte[] id = new byte[0];

    NdefRecord record = new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_MIME_MEDIA, mimeBytes, id, dataBytes);
    NdefMessage message = new NdefMessage(new NdefRecord[]{record});

    return message;
  }


 private void checkNfcEnabled()
  {
    Boolean nfcEnabled = NFC_Adapter.isEnabled();
    if (!nfcEnabled)
    {
    
    }
  }

}
```

It rightly triggers if I bring my Tag close to my phone, but stops at `Tag = null`, on the onResume method. Why is `Tag = null`. With that it does not write to the tag. Please help and point me in the right direction.

Comment: Yes. Thank you very much. I discarded everything and wrote a new one using  'enableReaderMode' with a callback instead of enableForegroundDispatch with intents.

Comment: Yes `enableReaderMode` is much better to use and does not have the problem of `PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE`